# Android Studio 3 and Gradle 4.3 -> Library modules no longer process local JARs -> how to handle this?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

Upgrade to Android Studio 3.0.0 mentions this, and doesn't elaborate on how to handle it:

`Library modules no longer process local JARs. This is to speed up incremental builds that are caused by changes to a library module's code.`

So I have a project with a library project in it. In my library project's `build.gradle` file I have this:

```
compile files('libs/com.somelib.somepackage.jar')
```

I changed `compile` to `implementation` and when I tried to run my app, all my classes that tried to access the `import com.somelib.somepackage.SomeClass` import statement threw an error that this package didnt exist.

I changed back to `compile` and I was able to build and run my app.

I want to comply to the new rules since `compile` is deprecated and will be removed with the next Gradle release, so how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Use `api` instead of `implementation`, if I am reading [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations) correctly.

Comment: @CommonsWare that was it. Thank you so much. They should really put some more effort in clarifying what `implementation` and `api`s purposes are

Comment: @CommonsWare I also tried that but my app module complains about unresolved dependencies even though app is not using JARs at all. Instead I have added new modules and chosen in Wizard "Import JAR/AAR Package". Depending on this new module worked well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to access classes from the .jar that is included in the library project from the app project, you will have to use `api` instead of implementation otherwise the classes will only be accessible in the library project:

```
implementation files('libs/com.somelib.somepackage.jar')
```

should be

```
api files('libs/com.somelib/somepackage.jar')
```

As said by the documentation:

> ... When a module includes an api dependency, it's letting Gradle know
>   that the module wants to transitively export that dependency to other
>   modules, so that it's available to them at both runtime and compile
>   time ...

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations